# Html Page header not on top

Tags: html, css

I have a SPA application that is to display a fixed header at the top of the page. This is normally working except that there are some pages that, when scrolling down, some contents of the pages is shown **on top** of the header (I mean, from the layer point of view, not the location).

For instance, certain `divs` are hidden by the header, but buttons within those `divs` are shown on top of the header.

Is there a way to force the header to be **always on top**?

Thanks!!

Comment: Use a higher `z-index` on the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its about z index property of your fixed header.. increase the z-index property set it to something like 9999 so that it is always above everylayer..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index` for this...

HTML:

```
<header></header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
z-index:9999;
}
```

The value of `z-index` should be higher than all other `Div`s

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, your problem can be fixed with the z-index CSS property, but I think the root of your problem lies deeper than this. You need to check your components for the position CSS property, it is possible that you missed to add it (along with z-index) on some divs/components.

Comment: Thank you @bojanfriscic for your comments. Just to let you know that, as soon as I added to the header the z-index, it all worked perfectly.